# Sync iTunes U and Android?

Tags: sync, podcast, itunes

I am a huge fan of the podcasts on iTunes, as well as the iTunes U material. However, I'm having a terrible time finding a slick system to sync the two. Doubleplay never really worked all that great for me. Any other good solutions anyone has used?

I have a Droid Incredible running 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These guys](http://androidtipguys.com/2011/06/how-to-sync-android-with-itunes/) recommend iSyncr as a solution. Cons: It's not free, and it won't sync copy-protected content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pasting the RSS url into Rhythmbox/Gpodder or another podcatcher, and transferring to device? After selecting the podcast in the podcasts section, simply drag and drop to the device on the left side of Rhythmbox when it is connected.

You may have some success with apps on the phone, specifically, I had seen something for subscribing iTunes podcasts in [Podax](https://github.com/thasmin/Podax#readme). I was having a similar problem accessing my university media on Android, and rewrote the [Tunesviewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tunesviewer/files/Android/) app for Android access, which may work better for you depending on what you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

I throw the podcast feeds into my Google Reader account, and then use Google Listen on my droid, automatically downloads the pod casts

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Reader is being retired and Google Listen has been killed.

Comment: Yeah, this sucks. Looking for a replacement without great success. Google Reader was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively I can recommend the iTunes U App [“TuneSpace”](http://2kit.de/en/tunespace-itunes-u-android/) for Android

Comment: Not bad, but it seems to be missing podcast search and other features.

Comment: Apparently that page was removed? Is TuneSpace still around?

Comment: TuneSpace **is** still around, but you need to download the APK file and install as a third party source.  As of this moment, you can get it at http://downloadapk.net/TuneSpace.html