# Is there a valid Android alternative to iTunes U?

Tags: itunes

iTunes U makes the difference (at least, to me) when it comes to choosing a tablet for study purposes. Does it exist a valid Android alternative to Apple's iTunes U?

For those who don't know iTunes U, it is a service that allows students and teachers to manage, browse and view media (such as videos and pdf files) related to education.

Comment: Welcome to AE! I don't have any experience with it, but you may want to look at [this article](http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2012/06/11/tunesviewer-brings-itunes-u-to-android-linux/#.UrHMXJBDvPN). Apparently you can actually use iTunes University on Android. Kinda.

Comment: See also: [Sync iTunes U and Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14723) | [How to view iTunes U without iTunes?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Google Play for Education program [detailed here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/edu/index.html) and [here](http://www.google.com/edu/).

Answer (score 3):

[Tunesviewer](http://tunesviewer.sourceforge.net/) is an application for Linux or Android that "[allows]  access iTunes-University media and podcasts." *(From Tunesviewer main page)*.

You may want to check it out. There is an [APK installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tunesviewer/files/Android/tunesviewer-1.2.1.apk/download) to run on Android devices. It's also available [from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=tunesviewer&fdid=com.tunes.viewer).

Comment: It's in Fdroid repository as well - that may be a better option, as it tells when there are important updates to your apps.

Comment: @NoBugs Indeed it is. Thanks, I've added that to the answer!